# 'The database file is locked' with System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am suddenly getting the following errors from SQLite after adding a new transaction:

> The database file is locked database
>   is locked

Has anyone seen this?  I added an update transaction (following some successful selects/inserts).  I can't find anything different about this one...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out.  From looking at [this](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/909/4164.aspx) [really old] thread on the phxsoftware site, it seems like there can be locking problems if you don't immediately dispose of readers and commands after executing them.

I fixed my problem by making sure to not keep commands or readers around and surrounding them with using statements.

([Web archived version of the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621123911/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/909/4164.aspx))

Comment: I added a link to web archive