# Entity Framework with SQLite exception: The underlying provider failed on Commit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net

I'm using the Entity Framework (.NET 4.0) with SQLite as the underlying database and I get an exception when I try to commit some changes to the database:

> The underlying provider failed on Commit.

The stack trace is:

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Commit. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: The database file is locked
database is locked
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavi
or behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Commit()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at MySystem.MySystemService.UpdateFollowersAndUsers() in C:\Path\To\MySystem\MySystemService.cs:line 295
```

My code is pretty simple:

```
// Gets more followers for the competitor and updates the database
List<Follower> moreFollowers = GetMoreFollowers(competitor);

// Add the new followers to the database
using (MySystemEntities db = new MySystemEntities())
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Follower f in moreFollowers)
        {
            db.AddToFollowers(f);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

This snippet of code is inside `MyService`, it comes in with a batch of 5,000 followers and it's getting the above exception. However, when I pull the same snippet of code out into the `Main` function and just manually add a few followers, then it no longer throws the exception and the followers are successfully added to my database. **Apparently the database file is locked, what may be causing this issue?**

Comment: You mean it works when you add one follower, commit then add the next but not when first adding 5000 and then committing ?

Comment: No, I mean that I hard code adding 5-6 followers to the `moreFollower` list and then I use the same code snipped below and it works. I've tried moving the `db.SaveChanges()` inside the `foreach`-loop, but I got the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the answer in another SO question: ['The database file is locked' with System.Data.SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348860/the-database-file-is-locked-with-system-data-sqlite)

Ironically, the OP answers his own question too :).

Comment: That resource link no longer exists

Comment: @daveL did you figure out a resolution to this? I saw your comment on the linked question