# Entity Framework 4.1 and SQLite

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, system.data.sqlite

I'am using SQLite database and Entity Framework 4.1 Code First.

The following error occurred when `db.SaveChanges` called
`System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: The database file is locked`

My code:

```
using (var db = new Dal.Database())
{
    var newObj = db.Sheet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.SheetId == SheetId);
    if (newObj == null)
        newObj = new Dal.Sheet();

    newObj.SheetTypeCode = SheetTypeCode;
    newObj.SheetCount = SheetCount;

    db.Sheet.Add(newObj);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Please, help me.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of C# are you running?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a single database file correct? Does the app have permission to access that file? And is the file definitely not read only?

So the error occurs on SaveChanges, so that means that your code is successfully reading data from your database, but not writing?

These may have the answer for you,

[Entity Framework with SQLite exception: The underlying provider failed on Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192378/entity-framework-with-sqlite-exception-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-commit)

['The database file is locked' with System.Data.SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348860/the-database-file-is-locked-with-system-data-sqlite)

Try to isolate the error, what happens if you try to insert new data into your database without you reading from it first?

Is there an inner exception?

Comment: I came across some other stackoverflow answers about transaction issues, but you don't appear to be using a transaction? EF is probably using a transaction, but how does that affect this?

Comment: [Transactional(TransactionalTypes.TransactionScope)]
        protected override void DataPortal_Insert()
        {
         using (var db = new Dal.Database())
{
    var newObj = db.Sheet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.SheetId == SheetId);
    if (newObj == null)
        newObj = new Dal.Sheet();

    newObj.SheetTypeCode = SheetTypeCode;
    newObj.SheetCount = SheetCount;

    db.Sheet.Add(newObj);
    db.SaveChanges();
}}

Comment: what does the Transactional method decorator do?